# Is there any tool / endpoint to collect metrics from TGI image and filter these metrics?

Tags: huggingface, large-language-model

I am currently running a TGI container and collecting  metrics on its performance using /metrics endpoint. However, I only want to collect metrics for specific times and days. Is it possible to add a filtering feature to the TGI container that allows me to specify a time range and/or specific days of the week for which metrics should be collected?
For example, I would like to collect metrics between 9am-5pm, Monday through Friday. Will the metrics be reset each day, or will they continue to accumulate from the start time/day of the container? Additionally, are there any existing tools or methods that can be used to achieve this functionality?

i have tried using prometheus and and tried to introduce time when collecting metrics.